# C++ define functions based on template types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stl

Let's say I have the following struct `MyPairType`.

```
template<typename F, typename S>
struct MyPairType {
  F first;                                                                           
  S second;                                                                        
  MyPairType() { }
  MyPairType(F f, S s) { first = f; second = s; }
  operator F() const { return first; }
  operator S() const { return second; }
};
```

When I try to use `MyPairType<A, B>` (for any types `A` and `B` s.t. `A != B`), it works fine. However, when I try to use `MyPairType<T, T>` (for any type `T`), it fails because the two conversion operators are same:

```
error: ‘MyPairType<F, S>::operator S() const [with F = int; S = int]’ cannot be overloaded
   operator S() const { return second; } 
   ^
error: with ‘MyPairType<F, S>::operator F() const [with F = int; S = int]’
   operator F() const { return first; }
```

I found that this can be fixed using a combination of `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same`, but it would require templating the operator function which is not desirable.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
typedef int T1;
typedef int T2;
...
MyPairType<T1, T2> my_pair(3, 5);
T1 frst = my_pair;
T2 scnd = my_pair;
std::cout << frst << " " << scnd << std::endl;
```

For the above code, I want the output to be `3 5`. Can the conversion happen differently for `T1` and `T2` even though they both are `int`? How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can specialize the class for different types.

Answer (score 0):

Create a specialisation for the case they are the same. Note: To avoid this, you may want to do what the standard library does and provide methods for first and second element access rather the providing a casting method. This way even if the types are the same, the methods are different, so no overloading.

Anyways you can specialise by adding this after the original definition,

```
template<typename F>
struct MyPairType<F, F> {
  F first;                                                                           
  F second;                                                                        
  MyPairType() { }
  MyPairType(F f, F s) { first = f; second = s; }
  operator F() const { return first; }
};
```

Also, you constructors are incorrectly named. VPairType -> MyPairType.

EDIT: Just realised that this way you will never be able to access the second element by casting. You should just provide a `F first()` and `F second()` method